# Pause screen Canvas Not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

By clicking space you get the pause screen. I am trying to update the score but I think my if, if else loops are wrong, I am getting no error however. 
Just click here and while playing hit space:
http://www.taffatech.com/Snake.html
The code that is trouble I think is:

```
function SetSize()
{
if (document.getElementById('Easy').checked)
{
cellSize = 10;
Mode = 1;
} 

else if (document.getElementById('Medium').checked)
{
cellSize = 20;
Mode = 2;
} 

else if (document.getElementById('Hard').checked)
{
cellSize = 30;
Mode = 3;
} 
}

function init()
{


if (Mode == 1)
{
scoreEasy = easyScore;
if(score > scoreEasy) {

easyScore = scoreEasy;

}
}

else if (Mode == 2)
{
scoreMedium = mediumScore;
if(score > scoreMedium) {

mediumScore = score;

}
}

else if (Mode == 3)
{
scoreHard = hardScore;
if(score > scoreHard) {

highScore = score;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here

```
scoreHard = hardScore;
if(score > scoreHard) {
```

Should that be:

```
scoreHard = Math.max(score,hardScore);
```

And also `highScore = score;` in the `hardScore` part, shouldn't that be `hardScore = score;`?

Comment: Thank you I think I have it working, all except the easy score is showing NaN? What might solve this?